# How to set Tesseract response data to Vue data variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tesseract

This is probably a very simple question where I'm having trouble understanding Promises.

I'm trying to use Tesseract to read text from an image and then set the response to a data variable for use in my Vue application. I think I'm running into a Promise issue but can't work out what the solution is.

My script tag in the Vue component:

```
import { createWorker, PSM, OEM } from 'tesseract.js'

const worker = createWorker({
  logger: m => console.log(m)
})

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      textoutput: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    recognize: async () => {
      const img = document.getElementById('text-img')
      await worker.load()
      await worker.loadLanguage('eng')
      await worker.initialize('eng', OEM.LSTM_ONLY)
      await worker.setParameters({
        tessedit_pageseg_mode: PSM.SINGLE_BLOCK,
      });
      const { data } = await worker.recognize(img)
      console.log(data.text)

      // This is the action I want to perform
      this.textoutput = await data.text
    }
  }
};
```

My console output:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 
    [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): 
        "TypeError: Cannot set property 'textoutput' of undefined"
```

As I mentioned, I think I'm just not understanding JavaScript and how to set the `data` object to the returned response but I am struggling to work this out.

Comment: Try changing from an arrow-function: `async recognize() {`

Comment: Does the line `console.log(data.text)` give an expected output? If yes then it seems issue is `this` is `undefined`